# Participles of reflexive verbs

Tags: grammar, verb, reflexive, participle

> Mit der mittlerweile fünften Streikwelle will die Pilotengewerkschaft Vereinigung Cockpit Bewegung in **die festgefahrenen Tarifgespräche** bringen.

The verb [*festfahren*](http://dictionary.reverso.net/german-english/festfahren) normally needs to be used in reflexive form. When we turn it into the past participle *festgefahren,* don’t we need to keep the *sich* as in one of the following?

> die sich festgefahrenen Tarifgespräche
>   die sich festfahrenden Tarifgespräche

A similar example is:

> Der Mann befindet sich zurzeit in Frankfurt.

Which of the following, if any, should we say?

> der sich zurzeit in Frankfurt befindende Mann
>   der zurzeit in Frankfurt befindende Mann

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In principle** you can turn every reflexive verb into a participle keeping the *sich,* but you have to be careful about the tense and the grammatical voice:

> Der Mann befindet sich zurzeit in Frankfurt. → der sich zurzeit in Frankfurt befindende Mann
>
> Die Tarifverhandlungen haben sich festgefahren. → die sich festgefahren habenden Tarifverhandlungen

I am not aware of any example, in which the *sich* can be dropped when the verb is turned into a present participle – unless it is optional anyway such as for *sich flüchten.*

**However**, such constructions are very rarely used with reflexive verbs, for a number of reasons:

- Extended participle constructions are perceived as ugly and are difficult to understand.
- Often, the actor of the reflexive verb is clear from context and thus you can avoid such a construction by using a passive participle (which then does not need a *sich* anymore). Your first example is such a case:

  > Die Tarifverhandlungen haben sich festgefahren. → die von sich festgefahrenen Verhandlungen → die festgefahrenen Verhandlungen

  Note that in cases like this where there is no need to use *von sich,* using it nontheless may put unwanted emphasis on the actor. Thus in this example it would imply that there is actually nobody responsible for the situation, which is very unlikely.

  Some other examples:

  > die sich erholt habenden Urlauber → die erholten Urlauber
  >
  > die sich interessierenden Schüler → die interessierten Schüler
  >
  > der sich verirrt habende Wanderer → der verirrte Wanderer
  >
  > der sich besonnen habende Mönch → der besonnene Mönch

  I can only make out the imprecise criterion that for this to be possible, the origin of the reflexivity of the verb has to be obvious or the verb can also be used non-reflexively with an appropriate meaning. I can very well imagine that the passive participles of those verbs are listed as autonomous adjectives in dictionaries. Some examples where this is not possible:

  > der sich in Frankfurt befindende Mann → <s>der in Frankfurt befundene Mann</s>
  >
  > der sich bedankende Empfänger → <s>der bedankte Empfänger</s>
  >
  > der sich übergebende Oktoberfestbesucher → <s>der übergebene Oktoberfestbesucher</s> (this would actually be a possible sentence but it means something entirely different)
- Also rather often, there is another word whose meaning is identical or similar to the original and thus preferred. This is often facilitated by the word being etymologically related to the original verb:

  > die sich freuenden Gewinner → die fröhlichen Gewinner
  >
  > die sich beeilenden Rettungskräfte → die eilenden Rettungskräfte
  >
  > der sich bedankende Empfänger →  der dankbare Empfänger
  >
  > die sich in Wasser lösende Substanz → die wasserlösliche Substanz
  >
  > der sich übergebende Oktoberfestbesucher → der brechende Oktoberfestbesucher
  >
  > die sich ergebenden Probleme → die resultierenden Probleme
  >
  > der sich in Frankfurt befindende Mann → der in Frankfurt weilende Mann

  Note that the above constructions are not identical in meaning, but the difference does not matter in many contexts.

Answer (score 3):

**Present participle of reflexive verbs**

You have to keep the pronoun.

> Der sich in Frankfurt befindende Mann.

**Past participle of reflexive verbs**

Ditch the pronoun.

> Die festgefahrenen Tarifgespräche.

**Yet you cannot always form a semantically equivalent participle:**
<sup>In the following, *reflexive* refers to fully reflexive verbs, where *Ich [verb] dich.* is not possible.</sup>

> Der Lehrer hat sich geirrt. → <strike>der geirrte Lehrer</strike>

Here, the meaning of *Der Lehrer ist [durch eine Stadt] geirrt.* would be assumed. Another example is

> Die Studentin hat sich ausgekannt. → <strike>die ausgekannte Studentin</strike>

In general you can circumvent such inconsistencies by disguising the past participle as a present participle (as Wrzlprmft demonstrated; der sich geirrt habende Lehrer, die sich ausgekannt habende Studentin).

Usually such exceptions are of intransitive nature (*sich* has little meaning, so it doesn't really count as an object), like the two examples above, but even for these exceptions there are exceptions in turn:

> Das Kind hat sich erkältet. → das erkältete Kind

Answer (score 1):

According to *Duden – Deutsches Universalwörterbuch, 5. Aufl. Mannheim 2003*, there are two possibilities:

> **fest|fah|ren**  <st. V.>:
>   **a)** *(mit einem Fahrzeug) in etw. so stecken bleiben, dass die Räder o. Ä. nicht mehr greifen, sich nicht mehr drehen* <ist>: das Auto ist im Schnee festgefahren; **Ü** die Verhandlungen sind festgefahren;
>   **b)** <f. + sich> *(von einem Fahrzeug) so festgefahren* (a) sein, dass ein Weiterkommen nicht mehr möglich ist <hat>: der Lkw fuhr sich im Morast fest; **Ü** die Verhandlungen haben sich festgefahren.

Comment: Thanks, then maybe my example wasn't a good one to get to the point. I've edited to add another example.

Answer (score 0):

"fest**ge**fahren" ist partizip perfekt.
In deinem Beispiel drückt diese Form die Teilhabe der Pilotenvereinigung an den festgefahrenen Gesprächen aus.

Das Partizip Perfekt wird generell mit dem Präfix **ge-** gebildet, das in deinem Fall auf **fahren** angewandt wird. (ge-fahren -> fest-ge-fahren).

> Das Partizip Perfekt wird dagegen mit der Vorsilbe „ge-“ (wird bei Verben mit anderen Vorsilben und solchen auf -ieren weggelassen) und durch Anhängen von „-t“ oder „-et“ (bei regelmäßigen Verben) bzw. „-en“ und weiteren Veränderungen (bei unregelmäßigen Verben) gebildet.

Andere Beispiele:

**hervorheben**
(To put something or someone over others)

```
Erst nach dem Hervorheben wurde uns die Wichtigkeit des Anliegens klar.

Die Wichtigkeit des Anliegens wurde uns erst klar, nachdem wir es hervorgehoben hatten.
```

**Einstellen**
(to configure)

```
Wir müssen das Gerät erst richtig einstellen.

Endlich funktioniert das Gerät, denn wir haben es richtig eingestellt.
```

Wörter die mit **be-** beginnen werden nicht mit dem Präfix **ge-** zum Partizip Perfekt mutiert. Stattdessen wird die Zeit verändert und ein Hilfsverb beigestellt.
In deinem Beispiel wird aus **befinden**, je nach zeitlichem Kontext:

- (Der Mann) habe (sich in Frankfurt) befunden.

Deine Ausführungen zu **befinden** sind in diesem Kontext falsch. Der Mann befindet sich ja noch in Frankfurt(Gegenwart), wohingegen die Tarifgespräche der Pilotenvereinigung sich bereits festgefahren haben.(Vergangenheit)